# Let $X'$ and $X$ be metric spaces with measures $d$ and $d'$. Show that $m((p,p'), (q,q')) = \sqrt{d(p, q)^2 + d'(p,q)^2}$ is a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For the given metric  $m((p,p'), (q,q')) = \sqrt{d(p, q)^2 + d'(p,q)^2}$. I have proven the first two properties for a metric hold (this is rather trivial). I am unable to prove the triangle inequality. My work so far is as follows:

$$m((p,p'), (q,q')) = \sqrt{d(p, q)^2 + d'(p',q')^2} \le \sqrt{(d(p,r) + d(r, q))^2 + (d'(p',r') + d'(r', q'))^2} \\ \le \sqrt{(d(p,r) + d(r, q))^2} + \sqrt{(d'(p',r') + d'(r', q'))^2}$$

How can I continue from here? Was invoking $\sqrt{x+y} \le \sqrt x + \sqrt y$ helpful?

Comment: Your question isn't well-posed. $m$ should be a map from $(X\times X')^2$ to $[0,\infty)$. The way you have it written is as a map from $X\times X'$ to $[0,\infty)$. In particular the expression $d(p,q)^2 + d'(p,q)^2$ doesn't make sense unless $X=X'$, which need not be true.

Comment: @Math1000 Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*

Fixing notation, I assume you mean

$$m((p,p'), (q,q')) = \sqrt{ d(p,q)^2 + d'(p',q')^2}$$

This is a generalization of a Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^2$. You can prove the triangle inequality the same way as we do there. Namely, write

$$m((p,p'), (q,q'))^2 = \langle (d(p,q),d'(p',q')), (d(p,q),d'(p',q')) \rangle_{\mathbb R^2}^2$$

Your proof will require the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Try writing out the proof for $\mathbb R^2$. Then write it out for your metric $m$.